# Porcentagem de 0 a 5

Tags: php, matemática

Tenho um número do IMDB(Internet Movie Data Base), no caso o número é 7.7 de 10.
Preciso colocar este número em uma escala de 0 a 5(apenas inteiros).
Com base nesta resposta: https://stackoverflow.com/a/10201086/1844007

Eu usei:

```
$res = ($obj->imdbRating / 100) * 5;
```

Só que o resultado dá: **0.385** que não é a nota real do filme(7.7).
O que eu estou fazendo errado?

Código completo **corrigido** com a ajuda do [marcelo-bonifazio](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/users/14262/marcelo-bonifazio):

```
function imdb($filme) {
  $url = 'http://www.omdbapi.com/?i=&t=' . strtolower(str_replace(' ', '+', $filme));
  $json = file_get_contents($url);
  $obj = json_decode($json);
  $res = round($obj->imdbRating / 2,0);
  return $res;
}
```

Muito obrigado.

Comment: Tente `( $obj->imdbRating / 2 )`

Comment: Você está certo, poste seu comentário como resposta que vou marcar como melhor resposta, muito obrigado.

Comment: não considero como uma resposta rs, seu problema estava somente no calculo matemático... vou acrescentar uma função de arredondamento que funcione direito, ai coloco como resposta

Comment: Não sei se fiz certo: `round($obj->imdbRating / 2,0);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O seu problema esta principalmente no calculo, se for trabalhar apenas com valores inteiros, recomendo a utilização da função `round` junto com a função `intval`.

Isso porque se por acaso você for trabalhar somente com valores `int`, pode gerar algum conflito.

```
$obj = 7.7;
$new_value = $obj / 2;
// Valor real = 3.8
echo round( $new_value ).'</br>';
echo gettype ( round( $new_value )  ).'</br>';
// Imprime 4 e tipo double
echo intval ( $new_value ).'</br>';
echo gettype ( intval ( $new_value )  ).'</br>';
// Imprime 3 e tipo integer
echo intval ( round( $new_value ) ).'</br>';
echo gettype ( intval ( round( $new_value ) )  ).'</br>';
// Imprime 4 e tipo integer
```

Comment: Resposta simples porem me ajudou bastante, obrigado.